# How to use IF ELSE IF in put unformatted in Progress?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am having issues with a programm where I need to output different strings if a certain Database Field has a specific value.

Let's say I have a Database called `TestDB` with following Fields `Name`, `Age`, `Currency`

I am outputting the data into a .csv File so my company uses for that a lot of `put unformatted` statements.

The "output" part would look something like this:

> put unformatted
>
> > TestDB.Name ';'
> > TestDB.Age ';'
> > if TestDB.Currency = 1 then 'Euro' else ? ';'
> > if TestDB.Currency = 2 then 'Dollar' else ? ';'
> > if TestDB.Currency = 3 then 'Kuna' else ? ';' 
> > if TestDB.Currency = 4 then 'Pound' else ?
> > skip.

The problem with these `if's` is that if Currency is 1, it will output Euro, but for other `if's` still output ? in .csv File.
I want these if's to be structured like: `if... else if... else if... else`
So if the 1st if is correct, then all other `if's` would be skipped.

I tried in multiple ways, but failed every time.
Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
if TestDB.Currency = 1 then 'Euro' 
else if TestDB.Currency = 2 then 'Dollar' 
else if TestDB.Currency = 3 then 'Kuna'
else if TestDB.Currency = 4 then 'Pound' 
else ?
```

But a `CASE` statement might work better here

```
case TestDB.Currency:
  when 1 then curName = 'Euro'.
  when 2 then curName = 'Dollar'.
  when 3 then curName = 'Kona'.
  when 4 then curName = 'Pound'.
  otherwise curName = 'unknown'.
end case.
put unformatted curName skip.
```

Comment: That case statement actually helped me out a lot! Thanks a bunch!
It works flawlessly, damn. It never occured to me that I can use the CASE statement before the put unformatted, and then just output the variable in put unformatted.

Answer (score 1):

Since I doubt that **anyone** wants to see 1, 2, 3, 4 as currency you probably already have a `function` or `method` that performs this conversion.

```
class env.currency:

   method static character getName (
      i_icurrency as integer
   ):

      case i_icurrency:
         when 1 then return 'Euro'.
         when 2 then return 'Dollar'.
         when 3 then return 'Kuna'.
         when 4 then return 'Pound'.
      end case.

      return 'unknown'.

   end method.

end class.
```

And in use:

```
put unformatted
   TestDB.Name ';'
   TestDB.Age ';'
   env.currency:getName( TestDB.Currency ) ';'

   skip
   .
```